# Scheme function - take an atom and a list and return new list where the given atom occurrences are removed from given list

Tags: list, scheme

```
(define (remover lst n)
    (cond ((null? lst) ())
        ((eq? (car lst) n) (cdr lst))
        (else (cons (car lst) (remover (cdr lst) n)))))

(remover 'f '(a f c g f b))
```

This code generates the following error.

> car: expects argument of type ; given f

Comment: Judging by the argument names I would assume `lst` should be a list instead of the symbol `f`. The operation `car` only works on pairs and lists and not symbols. Also `n` is typical name for a numeric argument, like `5` and not a list. eg. with `(define  (list-ref lst n) ...)` it's clear the list is the first and the index is the second argument from the naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be calling `remover` with swapped arguments. If you call it like that:

```
(remover '(a f c g f b) 'f)
```

you will get the result `(a c g f b)`.

Since you want to remove all occurrences of the `f`, you will also have to change `(cdr lst)` into `(remover (cdr lst) n)`, like this:

```
(define (remover lst n)
    (cond ((null? lst) ())
        ((eq? (car lst) n) (remover (cdr lst) n))
        (else (cons (car lst) (remover (cdr lst) n)))))
```

Then `(remover '(a f c g f b) 'f)` should also yield the expected result `(a c g b)`.

To have the arguments of `remover` switched you would have to switch them in in the definition and for both recursive calls, like this:

```
(define (remover n lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) ())
        ((eq? (car lst) n) (remover n (cdr lst)))
        (else (cons (car lst) (remover n (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: This is so helpful. Isn't there a method to get the result for

(remover 'f '(a f c g f b))

order as (a c g b)

I'm new to scheme

Comment: @AmanieWickramanayake The order is defined by you in the argument list of the procedure. You have chosen `lst`, then `n` when you write it like `(define (remover lst n) ...)`. YOU have the choice of both name and order. If you keep the names you switch it by makeing it `(remover n lst)`. You also need to update where you call the function by switching the order there too.

Comment: @AmanieWickramanayake I have added a description of how to have the arguments switched in the answer.

Comment: Okay! I got that perfectly now.
Thank you very much @Sylwester and martin_joerg